# Сделать метку [Internet] синонимом [Интернет]

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Сейчас в описании метки [интернет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82), написано что её использовать **нельзя**. Метка [internet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet) без описания и используется.

Предлагаю их объединить, чтобы обе не использовались.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Синонимизировал и объединил эти метки. Основной сделал [интернет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82).

Comment: Я, может, уже поздно спрашиваю, но зачем вообще эти метки нужны?

Comment: @vadimovchinnikiv если их удалить, то кто-нибудь сразу их создаст.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov если есть желание удалить метку, то можно создать вопрос с меткой [meta-tag:удаление-метки] (: