# Удалить [интернет] и поместить в чёрный список

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, удаление-метки, чёрный-список-меток

Увидев [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10481/220571), понимаю что метка [интернет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82) и её синоним [internet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet) по сути-то и не нужны.

- Невозможно построить границы, где эта метка уместна, чтобы оне охватывала почти все вопросы (так как программирование очень часто так или иначе связано с программированием систем, которые находятся на разных ПК, связанными через Интернет). По сути очень похожа на мета-метку.
- Метка ничего полезного не добавляет в сам вопрос.
- Нельзя по ней быть экспертом, поэтому не имеет смысла на неё подписываться или искать вопросы.
- В [описании метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82/info) прямо просится её не использовать

  > НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ. Метка слишком общая, используйте метки, указывающие используемые технологии, протоколы, библиотеки, языки программирования.
- На enSO такая метка [была довольно давно удалена](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255169/1548895).

Так как удаление означает редактирование кучи вопросов вручную (169 вопросов на момент написания) я вижу данную работу слишком трудоёмкой плюс она может быть через время воскрешена, поэтому предлагаю сразу её внести в чёрный список.

Comment: Название этого вопроса еще лучше чем прообраз на enSO: "_I want to delete the [internet]_"

Comment: В своё время метку "ошибка" [выпилили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/549/15479), а там вопросов побольше было. Просто каждый день по чуть-чуть редактировали вопросы)

Comment: ни нада удалять интернет

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik так удаляем или нет?

Comment: @AlexR. нужно постепенно осторожно править старые вопросы, да.

Comment: А как осторожно и почему постепенно?  За вечер раз и все?

Comment: @AlexR. после этих правок вопросы будут на главной всплывать. Части участников это не нравится. Поэтому лучше понемногу)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik А чем помещение вопросов в чёрный список плохо? Вы же сами против всплывания вопросов на главной. И я не считаю, что надо тратить чьё-то время на то, что можно сделать автоматически.

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич Почему?

Comment: Мне кажется это вполне себе рабочая метка, бывают вопросы относящиеся к интернету как к сети, когда вопрос предполагает проблему, например, с маршрутизацией или протоколом.

Comment: @Mamba Так вопрос и должен иметь соответствующую чёткую метку, а не эту. Есть метки [tag:маршрутизация] и [tag:сеть], а также для каждого известного протокола.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, кто-то совершенно не умеет в юмор

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Задача завершена. Метка сгорела и больше не может использоваться.