# Нет перевода при попытке повесить системную метку [untagged]

Tags: дефект, локализация, метки, чёрный-список-меток

Есть такая метка по всей сети и называется она [untagged](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged). Она появляется на вопросе только в том случае, если система удалила с него все остальные метки (например, при сжигании мета-метки, или если с меткой только один вопрос и ей полгода (на мете год), то она автоматически удаляется. Но других меток на вопросе может и не быть). Вручную эту метку поставить якобы невозможно. Я решил это проверить и получил:

> This tag is for use by the system for questions that have had all other tags removed. Please use a [real tag](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) instead.

(ссылка под словом `real tag` — ссылка на текущий сайт, в моём случае это наша мета).

Пробовал искать строку в transifex, но ничего не нашёл. Не публикую на MSE, так как только-только осваиваю систему перевода, и может быть, я как-то не так искал.

Скриншот дефекта:

[image: Скрин дефекта]

Comment: Это описание доступно для редактирования только сотрудникам. Недавно добавляли такое для [internet](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13107/176217) как раз.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а если метку снять со всех вопросов и заменить на что-нибудь, то оно пропадёт? И просто будет написано, что метка запрещена?

Comment: Это описание появляется при попытке добавить метку. От количества существующих оно не зависит.

Comment: Закрыл вопрос как дубликат.